# How does native speaker express "The effects were obvious" after applying eye cream to my eyes for 1 month

Tags: expressions

My questions: I want to express that I can see the difference after I began to use an eye cream. I am wondering if native speakers would use this expression like I did in the title "The effects were obvious" or other expressions. Can any friend help me with this?

Comment: "The cream had a _noticeable_ effect"?

Comment: Both are fine, "The effects were obvious" and "noticeable". There is a humorous acronym, too, IOTETMCO, https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/IOTETMCO . Not too common, except perhaps in academic environment. e.g., "The proof of the Pythagorean theorem is IOTETMCO," perhaps used sarcastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although medicines do have positive effects, we tend not to refer to them as 'effects'. When you think about it, many medicines are intended to restore something to normal, perhaps that is why we don't think of them as affecting a change. Unwanted 'side-effects' are things we would not normally expect to see or want, and the word tends to be reserved for these.

I think the most idiomatic way to express what you mean is to use a word you already used yourself - 'difference'. When we see a positive result from any change, we tend to speak about the 'difference' in a positive way:

> The *difference* was obvious / noticeable / immediately noticeable.

Comment: Thank you so much. my friend! I havn't thought of using difference. But after you explanation I see where you coming from. I think the word difference fits best. Thanks for binging out this idiomatic way of expression. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

"The effects were obvious" is a normal way to describe this.

It's not the *only* way, but it is grammatical and it expresses the idea you want to give.